# Django /admin/ page not showing

Tags: django, admin

I'm trying to follow "[Writing your first Django app, part 2](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/)", but I seem to have hit a wall.

While my server is running, the URL `domain:8000/admin/` returns exactly the same thing as `domain:8000/`, instead of showing me the administration site.

What can cause this issue, and what do I need to do to make sure my /admin/ URL loads the administration site?

Comment: Could you give more background info? How is you `urls.py`, if I'm correct, there are a couple of lines that must be uncommented. Additionally, try restarting the server, if you are not using the development server, there are chances that the code changes weren't picked up.

Comment: your settings and url codes

Comment: The problem is that the documentation still does not make clear that you have to edit your urls.py to enable the admin side of things. The answer below by Fernando contains all the steps to get this working correctly. Thanks @Fernando

Answer (score 15, accepted):

First of all: Inside your INSTALLED_APPS tuple, in settings.py you have to enable: `'django.contrib.admin'`.

Second: you have to run `python manage.py syncdb` after you enable the Django admin app.

Finally: To set your admin correctly, be sure that your urls.py look like this:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

# Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    #YOUR URLS GO HERE 

    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

Comment: You were correct : my 'django.contrib.admin' was commented and thus inactive. The Django tutorial at the time did not suggest this edit, but I believe it has now been corrected. Thanks !